# Algorithm to fill arrays php

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

I have the following problem:
I have 3 arrays say `a`, `b`, `c` each one of them has a size in between 0 and 20.
Then I have another array `target` that have a size of 20(as a maximum) and has to be filled up with the values contained in `a`, `b`, `c`. 
The ideal distribution in `target` should be 8 elements from `a`, 6 from `b` and 6 from `c`.
However, in case I don't have enough element in one of the three array I need to add elements from the other two, in a balanced manner.
For instance: if `c` has only 4 elements, then `target` needs to be filled up with 9 elements of `a`, 7 elements of `b` and the 4 coming form `c`. 
What I am trying to find is the wanted size of each of the three original arrays `a`, `b` `c`, so that later on I'll be able to add the elements to `target`.
I have to do this using `php` and I am struggling a bit. I came up with this solution:

```
<?php

// count of the elements in the three original arrays
$a_count = 20;
$b_count = 20;
$c_count = 4;

// size of the target array
$total_count = 20;
if($a_count + $b_count + $c_count < 20)
  $total_count = $a_count + $b_count + $c_count;

// the size desired at the end of the process
$a_wanted_size = 0;
$b_wanted_size = 0;
$c_wanted_size = 0;

$a_more = true;
$b_more = true;
$c_more = true;

$total = 0;

if($a_count > 8){
  $a_wanted_size = 8;
  $total += $a_wanted_size;
}
if($b_count > 6){
  $b_wanted_size = 6;
  $total += $b_wanted_size;
}
if($c_count > 6){
  $c_wanted_size = 6;
  $total += $c_wanted_size;
 }

if($a_count <= 8){
  $a_wanted_size = $a_count;
  $total += $a_count;
  $a_more = false;
}
if($b_count <= 6){
  $b_wanted_size = $b_count;
  $total += $b_count;
  $b_more = false;
}
if($c_count <= 6){
  $c_wanted_size = $c_count;
  $total += $c_count;
  $c_more = false;
}

echo("total ".$total);
while($total < $total_count){
  if($a_more == true && $total < $total_count){
     $a_wanted_size++;
     $total++;
  }
  if($b_more == true && $total < $total_count){
      $b_wanted_size++;
      $total++;
  }
  if($c_more == true && $total < $total_count){
      $c_wanted_size++;
      $total++;
  }
}// end of while

echo"RESULT <br>";
echo("a ".$a_wanted_size."<br>");
echo("b ".$b_wanted_size.'<br>');
echo('c '.$c_wanted_size.'<br><br>');

echo("total ".$total);
```

However, it looks a bit too complex for me, and maybe error prone, any better idea?
Thank you!

Comment: Are `a`,`b`, and `c` the same arrays as `local`, `national`, and `travel` ?

Answer (score 1):

This is my suggestion. Disclaimer: untested code.

```
$a_count = count($a);
$b_count = count($b);
$c_count = count($c);
$total_count = $a_count + $b_count + $c_count;
$target = array();
$i = 0;

$total_needed = 20;

if($total_count <= $total_needed)
{
    $target = array_merge($target,$a);
    $target = array_merge($target,$b);
    $target = array_merge($target,$c);
}
else
{
    while(isset($a[$i]) && isset($b[$i]) && isset($c[$i]) && ($i <= $total_needed))
    {
        array_push($target, $a[$i]);
        array_push($target, $b[$i]);
        array_push($target, $c[$i]);
        $i += 3;
    }
    for(; $i <= $total_needed; $i++)
    {
        if(isset($a[$i]) && isset($b[$i]))
        {
            array_push($target,$a[$i]);
            array_push($target,$b[$i]);
            $i += 2;
        }
        elseif(isset($b[$i]) && isset($c[$i]))
        {
            array_push($target,$b[$i]);
            array_push($target,$c[$i]);
            $i += 2;
        }
        else
        {
            if(isset($a[$i])) {
                array_push($target,$a[$i]);
                $i++;
            }
            elseif(isset($b[$i])) {
                array_push($target,$b[$i]);
                $i++;
            }
            elseif(isset($c[$i])) {
                array_push($target,$c[$i]);
                $i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

First, if there's less than or exactly 20 in all 3 arrays combined it just pushes all of the values. Otherwise, it tries to push 3 at a time, if that fails, it tries to push 2 at a time, if that fails it pushes 1 at a time until you get to 20.